# opensearch-dashboard proxy authentication not working as expected

Tags: authentication, proxy, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am having two issues with proxy authentication in opensearch-dashboards. I have been following the instructions here: [OpenSearch Dashboards Proxy Authentication](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.5/security/authentication-backends/proxy/#opensearch-dashboards-proxy-authentication). I have a proxy (Spring Gateway) that is adding the following headers: x-forwarded-for, x-proxy-user, x-proxy-roles. If I configure the `requestHeadersAllowlist` to include `x-forwarded-for`, proxy authentication in os dashboards doesn't work at all. I just get 401s and opensearch has a statement saying "XFF not done". If I remove `x-forwarded-for`, proxy authentication works well.

Except, and here is my issue, when I go to Dev Tools / Console and submit a request, I get prompted for a username / password. Not sure why the behavior of Discover is different from Dev Tools / Console or how to fix it. I have put a gateway between OS-Dashboards and OS to log the provided headers and in none of the cases is `x-forwarded-for` passed, even when the OS log states that XFF was resolved.

**UPDATE**
Interestingly, if I update everything to use a custom header (`ap-forwarded-for`) instead of `x-forwarded-for` everything seems to work.